# List of petuchot and/or setumot in Eicha

Tags: mesorah-tradition, lamentations-eicha

This seems to be a stupid question to me but here goes.

Does anyone have a list of the petuchot and setumot for Megillat Eicha? I am on a train for the next several hours and my beautiful Koren Kinnot is presently packed into my suitcase, leaving it inaccessible until I get home. Nonetheless, I think that this is a useful question to have here, as a quick search of the net turned up no results for the positioning of the petuchot and setumot in Eicha.

Comment: There are different ways

Comment: @DoubleAA, oy, I've only seen Koren's breakup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Mechon Mamre's text of Eicha](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c32.htm).

It looks like in the first, second, and fourth *prakim*, there is a *setumah* between every pasuk, and a *petuchah* at the end of the perek. In the third perek, the *setumah* is after every 3rd pasuk.
In the fifth perek, there is a *petuchah* after verse 18 (עַ֤ל הַר־צִיּוֹן֙ שֶׁשָּׁמֵ֔ם).

However, this is not uniform. For example, in my *tikkun kor'im* (Simanim), it places a *setumah* between each pasuk in the third perek as well.

Comment: This is not the uniform set-up. (It differs, for instance, from the scroll I read out of two nights ago.)